# Python: parse json list

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a json file, `data.json`

```
{
    "Nitrogen": [
        0.0173,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        28.0135
    ],
    "Oxygen": [
        0.0283,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        31.9988
    ]
}
```

I read the data like this:

```
import json

def read_data(path):
    with open(path, 'rU') as data:
        gasses = json.load(data)
        for gas in gasses:
            yield gas


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for row in read_data('data.json'):
        print(row)
```

It gives me

```
Nitrogen
Oxygen
```

How do I also get the value in the list instead?

Comment: `for gas in gasses.items():`

Comment: also, you have a typo ,is `yield` not `yeild`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
gasses = json.load(data)
for gas, value in gasses.items():
    yield (gas, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

gas points to the key of your dictionary. gasses[gas] gives you the value.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example** — Tested with Python ***2.6.9*** and ***2.7.10*** and ***3.2.5*** and ***3.4.3*** and ***3.5.0***

```python
import json


def read_data(path):
    with open(path, 'rU') as data:
        gasses = json.load(data)
        for gas, values in gasses.items():
            yield gas
            for value in values:
                yield value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for row in read_data('data.json'):
        print(row)
```

**Output**

```
Nitrogen
0.0173
0
0
0
28.0135
Oxygen
0.0283
0
0
0
31.9988
```